# How to create new file in java from blob with faster speed

Tags: java, streaming, java-io, filestreams

I have byte array of file in database. I am creating java file from it. But it is consuming more time. Is there any way to create file faster than it. My attempts are as follows >>>

```
    Blob blob = null
while (rs.next()) {
                results.add([
                    blob = rs.getBlob("document")
                ])

File outputFile = new File("D:" + File.separator + it.documentDesc + extension);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
IOUtils.copy(blob.getBinaryStream(), fout);
File file = new File("D:" + File.separator + it.documentDesc + extension)
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with your approach except that you can use IOUtils.copyLarge() instead of copy() method.

Comment: if you are expecting only one row from resultset, you should use if(rs.next()) instead of while.